# I need to create a loop to display images

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the html is very simple but it does what it needs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css.css">
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
    <title>Nasa</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="bg bg2"></div>
<div class="bg bg3"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>Nasa Images</h1>
<div class="search">
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="button" id="search" placeholder="Search" value="Search">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="content" class="contentbox">
  
</div>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
    
</footer>
</html>
```

---

Here is the js I don't know if this is the best way to doit but I hope it makes sense.

```
// Window load will wait for the website to load and then run the script 
window.addEventListener('load' , function(){
const bnt = document.querySelector('#search') //Declaring the button 
const box = document.querySelector('#searchbox').value//Declaring the Search Box


async function search(){ //In this fuction the script will take rhe users imput make a searcha 
and save the information sendt from the API/Server
    let q = document.querySelector('#searchbox').value
    let url = "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q="+q+"&description&media_type=image"
    let response = await fetch (url);
    console.log(response)
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    displayData(data)
    console.log(q)

}
 
function displayData(data){ //In this fuction we will display the data recived from the server
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += " <h1>"+data.collection.items[0].data[0].description+"</h1>"
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+data.collection.items[0].links[0].href+"' width='955' />";
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+data.collection.items[1].links[0].href+"' width='955' />";
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+data.collection.items[2].links[0].href+"' width='955' />";
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+data.collection.items[3].links[0].href+"' width='955' />";
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+data.collection.items[4].links[0].href+"' width='955' />";

}

bnt.addEventListener('click', search); //This event will tell the script when the button as 
been pressed and will run the fuction search
})
```

I am new to this and I have done loops in the past but I don't know how will I be able to create a loop for this situation.

Comment: You've given us a lot of code - but no real question. Can you specify where / what your issue actually is? What's not working here?

Answer (score 0):

The API returns an array as response. So you can use a `foreach` loop to display the data.

For example

```
data.collection.items.forEach(item => {
    displayData(data);
})
```

And you will have to modify your function so that it can handle the data properly.

```
function displayData(data){ //In this fuction we will display the data recived from the server
document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += " <h1>"+item.data[0].description+"</h1>"
document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+item.links[0].href+"' width='955' />";
document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+item.links[0].href+"' width='955' />";
document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+item.links[0].href+"' width='955' />";
document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+item.links[0].href+"' width='955' />";
document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML += "<br /><img src='"+item.links[0].href+"' width='955' />";

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am honestly lost. I have been looking everywhere how to doit but it makes no sense to me. I there a way you could tell me how to handle the data?

Comment: I have updated the answer. This might behave abnormally as I don't know the response but you should be able to fix

Comment: I will look in to it see how to doit. I will update the post ones I find how to doit.